# On demand incremental NTFS partition backup

Tags: windows, backup, ntfs, incremental-backup

This is somewhat a continuation of [my related failed question](https://superuser.com/questions/46547/how-to-incrementally-backup-whole-hdd-to-external-from-windows). I've decided to go with a filesystem approach rather that the whole disk in one chunk. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. I'm thinking about extending my [SyncBackSE](http://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/) backup to my whole NTFS partition. Would there be any downsides to this or a better way to do it?

Other stuff:

The hard drive I'm backing up to is a 160 GB external that has one big NTFS partition. Since I'm trying for a mirroring strategy, I might redo the partitions to match my notebook's 160 GB drive (10 GB ext 3|~512 MB linux-swap|138.55 GB NTFS).

Also, if no multi-platform solutions happen to be part of the answer, I'll be opening up another question dealing with this in Linux (which could probably easily backup *both* ext3 and NTFS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My vote goes to TrueImage, one of the rare commercial software that I use. Works great, has tons of options and it not that expensive (~50USD). Version 2010 has a nice new feature, Try&Decide, that takes a snapshot of your entire drive that you can revert to later (I use it for testing new software).

On the Linux side I use [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/). I guess you could expose your Windows drives over SMB, and then use rsnapshot on them too.