# Backup solution for a whole HDD on a laptop?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, backup, laptop

I'm thinking about getting a laptop to replace my desktop except for gaming (rare these days).

However I'd like to know all my data on the laptop is backed up on another hard drive; especially when I go out of the house with the laptop.

What solutions are there?

Could I use a external hard drive of the same capacity (or greater) and when I plug it into the laptop I could run a app to update any necessary files.

The alternative would be to manually keep my important files on other drives.

The laptop would be dual boot Ubuntu/Windows7

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/46547/how-to-incrementally-backup-whole-hdd-to-external-from-windows

Answer (score 0):

If you're dualbooting (or quadbooting - i have a backup of a windows/windows/linux/(NotNamedOs)), [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) (either on a thumb drive, or as an additional boot option on your main system and a external hard drive is the best option.

Alternately, use the built in windows 7 backup system for the windows drive or pretty much any windows hosted backup system - even if they don't handle linux, they will make a raw image of the linux partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, just basically buy an external hard drive, run a backup utility such as [EaseUp To-Do Backup](http://www.todo-backup.com/) or [Drive Image XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) if you want to image your drive.

You can then install the two Operating Systems in Dual Boot and they can use your External HDD as a Data Storage drive for both OS's to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cheap/older computer laying around, you can use Windows Home Server which will do a nightly backup of your machine. It's easy to restore files or even the whole disk in the event it is damaged.